# Ultra-lightweight editor (like Python's IDLE) for C

Tags: text-editor, ide, windows-8, c, programming

One thing I don't like about C is how so many IDEs put things between me and my code. They force me to make solutions when all I want is a simple *.c* file, and they have cluttered displays when all I want is a text editor with some basic context coloring.

[Python's IDLE](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/IDLE_%28Python%29), while far from a perfect system, offers simplicity, letting me see exactly how my code works without any clutter.

I'm then looking for an equivalent program for C that has the following features:

- Can run the code easily (like how IDLE runs code with F5)
- Basic context coloring
- Ability to collapse `{}` blocks

[Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) can do the context coloring and the collapsible blocks, but does not seem to have an easy way to run the *.c* file.

It must run on Windows 8 and it must be gratis.

Comment: Since you can run a Python script, but you cannot run a _.c_ file, what do you need to do exactly? Do you need to compile it and/or run the resulting built executable? What C compiler are you using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[**Sublime Text**](http://www.sublimetext.com/3) should be able to do all three of your tasks:

> Basic context coloring

This generally happens automatically.

> Ability to collapse `{}` blocks

You can do this by using the "gutter" (the area where the line numbers are displayed). To fold a `{}` block, click on the triangle in the gutter that's on the same row as the `{` character.

You can also fold any arbitrary code block by first selecting it and then either:

- click the menu item <kbd>Edit → Code Folding → Fold</kbd>, or
- open the Command Palette (<kbd>Ctrl+Shift+p</kbd> by default on Windows), type in "Code Folding: Fold", and pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

> Can run the code easily (like how IDLE runs code with F5)

Save your file and press <kbd>F7</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl+b</kbd> to "build" it. One of these might just compile your code and the other one might compile and run it; I'm not sure. (Sublime is very configurable so I'm not sure that the behavior I'm seeing on my machine will match your experience running a fresh copy of Sublime.)

You can also build through the Command Palette (<kbd>Ctrl+Shift+p</kbd> → "Build") or the build menu (<kbd>Ctrl+Shift+b</kbd>).